# Android: Sqlite - Moving Values From One Table To Another

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to search for information in one table (DATABASE_FAV_EQUIP_TABLE) based on a value, pull that information, and then place it into another table (DATABASE_EQUIP_TABLE)  - checking first if it is not already there.  My code is below.  Nothing is crashing, and I am not getting any errors, however no information gets placed into the second table (DATABASE_EQUIP_TABLE).  I have gone over it several times and cannot figure out why this isn't working.

```
//takes all equip data from saved equip set, and puts into equip table
public String AddSavedEquipToEquipTable(String name) {

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_EQUIP};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_FAV_EQUIP_TABLE, columns, KEY_FAVNAME + "='" + name + "'", null, null, null, null);

    if (c == null){
        return null;
    }
    else if(c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            int iEquip = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EQUIP);
            String equip = c.getString(iEquip);

            CheckEquipTable(equip);

            c.moveToNext();

            } while (KEY_FAVNAME == name);
        }

    return null;
}


public void CheckEquipTable(String equip){

    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_EQUIP};
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    Cursor check = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_EQUIP_TABLE, columns, KEY_EQUIP + "='" + equip + "'", null, null, null, null);

    if(check == null){              
        cv.put(KEY_EQUIP, equip);
        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_EQUIP_TABLE, null, cv);
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void AddSavedEquipToEquipTable(String name) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_EQUIP};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_FAV_EQUIP_TABLE, columns, KEY_FAVNAME + "='" + name + "'", null, null, null, null);

    int iEquip = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EQUIP);
    while(c.moveToNext())
        CheckEquipTable(c.getString(iEquip));
}
```

I'll explain a few changes:

- The column index of `KEY_EQUIP` will not change so we only need to retrieve the index once
- In Java you **must** compare Strings with `if(name.equals(KEY_FAVNAME))` not `==`, `(KEY_FAVNAME == name)` is probably false.
- `ourDatabase.query()` will never return null, the smallest result will be an empty Cursor (as in `cursor.getCount() == 0`)
- `cursor.moveToNext()` returns true / false, and when the index is at -1 moveToNext() is the same as moveToFirst(). Also if the Cursor is empty then moveToNext() returns false.

Don't hesitate with any other questions with my suggestion. Hope that helps!

**Addition**

I didn't notice CheckEquipTable() was checking if a Cursor is null the first time:

```
if(check == null){
```

Change it like so:

```
if(check.getCount() == 0){
```

Comment: Just tried replacing my code with that, but it is still not putting anything into the second database.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still terrible at reading the logcat.  The only thing I see of significance is that the cursor is not finalized or closed.  But it is not showing as an error or anything.

Comment: I added an update. Closing the Cursors is simple just call `c.close()` at the end of both functions.

Comment: I am still looking over your edited answer...but just out of curiosity, is it necessary to close a cursor every time?

Comment: It prevents wasting the memory, which means a faster app. What API are you programming for (API 10 or higher)?

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your explanation and tips.  I tried changing everything as you said above, and it still not working.  I've tested to make sure that there is information in the first `DATABASE_FAV_EQUIP_TABLE`.  I don't know how to tell if it is just not finding anything because of something I am doing, or if it is not inserting what it is finding correctly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13135/discussion-between-sam-and-sillyfidget)

Answer (score 0):

Um, you should be able to do this solely in sqlite. I can help more if I had the table names / columns, but you would basically do a query like this.

```
INSERT INTO SomeTable(C, D)
SELECT A, B
FROM OtherTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SomeTable 
    WHERE A = C AND B = D 
)
```